# How to create a custom block theme template based on a post category?

Tags: block-editor

With the classic editor (i.e., many many years ago), I used `single-map.php` as a template file for all posts that have the "Map" category assigned to them.

How am I supposed to do it with the WP block editor (more specifically, using a child theme off of the twenty twenty-three template)? Do I still have to place a `single-map.php` file inside the `templates` folder, or what's the best practice of doing this nowadays, please?

Answer (score 0):

A post template for posts of a particular category has never been part of the template hierarchy. `single-map.php` would only work for posts that belong to a "map" [custom post type](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/), not a "map" category.

If you want the entire template to be editable in the Site Editor, you would create a `single-map.html` file in the `templates/` directory. If you don't want template editing then you create  `single-map.php` file the way you previously did.

Comment: I want it to be editable in the Site Editor, yes. Thank you, Jacob! And what do I have to add to it so that this `single-map.html` template is being used whenever the category "map" is applied to a post?